# android - Switching strings in a textView dynamically

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to switch the android:text of a textview with various strings that are to be dynamically retrieved from my strings.xml. When the user presses the button on the grid, it will return a unique identifier. I want to use this identifier to dynamically load a string into the Pronoun textView.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
      TextView Pronoun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Prounoun);
      chosen = ((TextView) v).getText();
      //Inserts the identifier of what button was pressed into the local string chosen".
      Pronoun.setText("R.string.Pronoun_" + chosen);
   }
}
```

When the button 'a' is pressed, 'chosen' holds the letter 'a', when joining this to the string naming format "Pronoun_", resulting in "Pronoun_a". The intention was to call upon the string at this location. In reality, the text is literally "R.string.Pronoun_a" instead of retrieving the actual string content of Pronoun_a. If the button 'b' is pressed, I want the string content of 'Pronoun_b' to show in the textView. I am new to java, merely trying to recreate a technique I learned in another language. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this (with your actual package name):

```
String resKey = "your.apps.package:string/Pronoun_"+chosen;
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(resKey, null, null);
Pronoun.setText(resId);
```

Also see the [API Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Note: As AND_DEV already mentioned, you'll have to use `ActivityName.this.getResources()`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

`Pronoun.setText("R.string.Pronoun_" + chosen);`

try below line

`Pronoun.setText(ActivityName.this.getString(R.string.Pronoun_) ++ chosen);`

it will work in activity context, but in onclick i think you should use `ActivityName.this.`  you can also use `context` variable if you already created. here ActivityName is you activity name of which ur code is written .